# Trying to find the correct word or phrasing

Tags: phrasing

I'm trying to find the right word or phrasing for a specific action.

Person A, wearing armour, is incapacitated on the floor. Person B (much physically larger) comes along and picks him up by slipping a hand through the cracks of his breastplate and then lifting him off the floor, lugging Person A along him like a luggage bag.

The way I worded it is very clunky and lacks clarity. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to phrase the action of Person A being picked up. If anyone, who is better at english, can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have duplicated the "lugging" and "luggage" ideas. Also "along him" doesn't work, did you mean "along *with* him"? I suggest **dragging Person A behind him like a luggage bag.**

Comment: I'll try to rephrase it. Like I said, the way I worded it is very clunky and lacks clarity but what I'm trying to express is: Person B bends down and picks Person A off the floor with one hand, gripping him by the collar of his breastplate and then carries him alongside him like a briefcase? Not really dragging him behind.

Comment: You can't pick someone up and carry him by the collar like a briefcase - it would have to at his centre of gravity - say his waist band or belt. Otherwise you would have to drag Person A.

Comment: He's wearing armour... the breastplate is rigid. Anyways, it's fiction. Even if it doesn't make sense, if anyone could help me out with the phrasing etc. That would be great.

Comment: It doesn't matter how rigid the breastplate is, you can't carry someone off the floor away from the centre of gravity. I already suggested better phrasing. If it's science fiction, introduce antigrav, otherwise fiction still has to be plausible. Aside: there is nothing worse than the star in a movie wearing spectacles with flat lenses. They ruin the whole thing.

Comment: Have you seen infinity war? Thanos does the same exact thing to Thor in the beginning of the film.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it amounts to a request for writing advice. If you specified a particular word or phrase that you think is incorrect or don't understand or suspect is ungrammatical, you might be able to edit your original question to pose an on-topic question about that particular problem.